# Add custom options to the wplink dialog

Tags: filters, links, visual-editor

I managed to add a custom option-select for images with

```
function attachment_field_credit( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'first_image', true );
    $isSelected1 = $field_value == '1' ? 'selected ' : '';
    $isSelected2 = $field_value != '1' ? 'selected ' : '';
    $form_fields['first_image'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Use as first image' ),
        'input' => 'html',
        'html' => "<select name='attachments[{$post->ID}][first_image]' id='attachments[{$post->ID}][first_image]'>
                    <option ".$isSelected1." value='1'>Yes</option>
                    <option ".$isSelected2."  value='2'>No</option>
                   </select>"
    );
    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'attachment_field_credit', 10, 2 );
```

Now I need to do almost the same for links. So if I click on `Pages -> Add New -> Insert / Edit Link` I get this:

[image]

Can I add another option-select field for those links? How to do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The dialog HTML comes from `WP_Editors::wp_link_dialog()` but no hooks in there.

We could instead use jQuery to append the custom HTML to the link dialog and try to override e.g. the `wpLink.getAttrs()`, because it's very short ;-)

Demo example:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('#link-options').append( 
        '<div> 
            <label><span>Link Class</span>
            <select name="wpse-link-class" id="wpse_link_class">
                <option value="normal">normal</option>
                <option value="lightbox">lightbox</option>
           </select>
           </label>
       </div>' );

    wpLink.getAttrs = function() {
        wpLink.correctURL();        
        return {
            class:      $( '#wpse_link_class' ).val(),
            href:       $.trim( $( '#wp-link-url' ).val() ),
            target:     $( '#wp-link-target' ).prop( 'checked' ) ? '_blank' : ''
        };
    }
});
```

I just did a quick test and it seems to work but needs further testing and adjustments when updating links. [Here's an old hack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170753/modify-links-when-inserted-by-wysiwyg-editor) that I did that might need a refresh.

### Update

It looks like you want to add the `rel="nofollow"` option to the link dialog, so let's update the above approach for that case:

We add the `rel` link attribute with:

```
/**
 * Modify link attributes
 */
wpLink.getAttrs = function() {
    wpLink.correctURL();        
    return {
        rel:        $( '#wpse-rel-no-follow' ).prop( 'checked' ) ? 'nofollow' : '',
        href:       $.trim( $( '#wp-link-url' ).val() ),
        target:     $( '#wp-link-target' ).prop( 'checked' ) ? '_blank' : ''
    };
}
```

If the `rel` attribute is empty, then it will be automatically removed from the link in the editor.

Then we can hook into the `wplink-open` event that fires when the link dialog is opened. Here we can inject our custom HTML and update it according to the current link selection:

```
$(document).on( 'wplink-open', function( wrap ) {

    // Custom HTML added to the link dialog
    if( $('#wpse-rel-no-follow').length < 1 )
        $('#link-options').append( '<div> <label><span></span> <input type="checkbox" id="wpse-rel-no-follow"/> No Follow Link</label></div>');

    // Get the current link selection:
    var _node = wpse_getLink();

    if( _node ) {
        // Fetch the rel attribute
        var _rel = $( _node ).attr( 'rel' );

        // Update the checkbox
        $('#wpse-rel-no-follow').prop( 'checked', 'nofollow' === _rel );
    }

});
```

where we use the following helper function, based on the `getLink()` core function, to get the HTML of the selected link:

```
function wpse_getLink() {
    var _ed = window.tinymce.get( window.wpActiveEditor );
    if ( _ed && ! _ed.isHidden() ) {
        return _ed.dom.getParent( _ed.selection.getNode(), 'a[href]' );
    } 
    return null;
}
```

Here's the output:

[image: no follow option]

with the following HTML:

[image: html]

ps: This could be tested further and might also be extended to support translations

Comment: I liked this answer a lot cause it looked so easy. Problem though was not just the updating of links, also if I had multiple links on the same site the value remained the last one which was chosen even if from a different link. Could still be useful for someone though!

Comment: I updated the answer with an no-follow-link example @caramba

Comment: Hey @birgire, how to retrieve value of `href` if user don't open the dialog but just use the very first popup box which has the placeholder: `Paste URL or type to search`?

Comment: I think I used the `mce_external_plugins` filter to load the script file or the `after_wp_tiny_mce` hook to inject the snippet (with the append part as a single line string), to test this. The `getAttrs` method here will only override the value from the link settings dialog, I haven't looked into how to override the value from the inline input. Maybe override the `wp_link_apply` command if possible? I think this might be a good new question ;-)  @Dan9

Comment: @birgire Thank you! Finally, I have found where to get it. WordPress uses `tinymce.ui.Control.extend.setUrl` in the plugin `wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wplink/plugin.js`.

Comment: great, good to know @Dan9

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the core, there's no trace of any filter or action in the `wp_link_dialog` function, which would have made your life easier...

Investigating how others has solved this problem, there's [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rel-nofollow-checkbox/) that does more or less the same as you want. Basically it deregisters the wplink.js, `wp_deregister_script('wplink');` and registers again a modified version of the file, this time including the desired extra field.

Although I don't think this is the best method (taking into account possible subsequent conflicts while updating WordPress), I think that it is the easiest wat to get it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the information and plugin link. I will also look into the plugin and see how they solved it...

Comment: I solved it with looking at the source of the plugin mentioned in this answer which can be found on github https://github.com/ffsantos92/rel-nofollow-checkbox if anyone needs it. I only had to change 5 words or so ...

Answer (score 2):

This is my simple solution, it will add an checkbox without overriding 'wplink.js'

```
add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts', function() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    (function($) {
      $(function() {
        $(document).on("wplink-open", function(inputs_wrap) {
          $("#link-options").append(
            $("<div></div>").addClass("link-nofollow").html(
              $("<label></label>").html([
                $("<span></span>"),
                $("<input></input>").attr({"type": "checkbox", "id": "wp-link-nofollow"}),
                "rel=\"nofollow\""
              ])
            )
          );
          if (wpLink && typeof(wpLink.getAttrs) == "function") {
            wpLink.getAttrs = function() {
              wpLink.correctURL();
              <?php /* [attention] Do not use inputs.url.val() or any input.* */ ?>
              return {
                href: $.trim( $("#wp-link-url").val() ),
                target: $("#wp-link-target").prop("checked") ? "_blank" : null,
                rel: $("#wp-link-nofollow").prop("checked") ? "nofollow" : null
              };
            };
          }
        });
      });
    })(jQuery);
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <?php
}, 45);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was looking to add the checkbox to **enable 'rel=sponsored'** as Google has recommended that sponsored posts be marked Sponsored now instead of No Follow from 2020.

```
/**
 * Custom scripts for Admin
 */

jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    // Adding custom checkbox to enable sponsored link
    jQuery( '#link-options' ).append( '<div><label><span></span> <input type="checkbox" id="wpse-rel-sponsored"/> Sponsored Link</label></div>');

    // Override buildHtml function from wplink.js
    wpLink.buildHtml = function(attrs) {
        var sponsored = jQuery( '#wpse-rel-sponsored' ).prop( 'checked' ) ? true : false;
        var html = '<a href="' + attrs.href + '"';

        if ( sponsored && attrs.target ) {
            html += ' rel="sponsored" target="' + attrs.target + '"';  // 'Sponsored' and 'New tab' selected
        } else if ( sponsored ) {
            html += ' rel="sponsored" '; // Only 'Sponsored' selected
        } else if ( attrs.target ) {
            html += ' rel="noopener" target="' + attrs.target + '"'; // Only 'new tab' selected
        }
        return html + '>';
    }
} );
```

[image]