# TinyMCE default link target to "_blank"

Tags: customization, tinymce

I am struggling to change the `default_link_target` to `"_blank"`.
Here is what i have in `functions.php`:

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $settings ) {

    $settings['default_link_target'] = "_blank";
    return $settings;

}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE', 1000 );
```

This does not give any result, althought the overall approach is correct, as changing another setting works, for example when modifying the default height :

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $settings ) {
    $settings['height'] = 800;
    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE', 1000 );
```

Any ideas ?

Cheerz...

Johan

Comment: WordPress 4.5 introduced the inline link editor, so perhaps the tinyMCE settings are no longer effective for changing the link behavior. Browsing through the tinyMCE related PHP and JS, I didn't see any kind of filter or option to allow this and found [this post on Make WordPress Core](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/08/link-modal-wplink-changes-in-wordpress-4-5/) where the whole idea was poo-pood on pretty hard. It's still likely possible to do, but I presume it would require some JS being loaded with tinyMCE that handles the `#wp-link-target` checkbox.

Comment: sure! [Add custom options to the wplink dialog](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228553/add-custom-options-to-the-wplink-dialog) has some great insights on taking this further.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by replacing the wplink plugin with tinyMCE's default link plugin, and then using the original function as is.

I created my own plugin though for the whole tinyMCE editor, and then copy/pasted the individual plugin folders from wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins, and then only included the 'link' plugin, so what I wound up with was like this:

```
function tiny_bbp_visual_editor_buttons( $buttons = array() ) {
        $buttons['tinymce'] = array(

        // Add the link button in the toolbar
            'toolbar1' => 'link'
        );

        return $buttons;
    }


function my_format_TinyMCE( $settings ) {

        // Set the target to blank

        $settings['default_link_target'] = "_blank";
        return $settings;
    }

function tiny_bbp_visual_editor_plugins( $plugin_array ) {

        // Add the link plugin

        $plugin_array['link']       = plugins_url( '/mce/link/plugin.min.js', __FILE__ );

        return $plugin_array;
    }
```

Note: I used this for bbPress, and so I used specific bbPress filters for parts of it. But for the standard editor, I'd think you can leave out the first two filters:

```
add_filter( 'bbp_after_get_the_content_parse_args', 'tiny_bbp_enable_visual_editor' );

add_filter( 'bbp_after_get_the_content_parse_args',  'tiny_bbp_visual_editor_buttons' );

add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'tiny_bbp_visual_editor_buttons' );

add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'tiny_bbp_visual_editor_plugins' );

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE', 1000 );
```

(It should go without saying, but this code will give you a TinyMCE editor that only includes a "Link" button...)